# Definição de "setas" em PHP

Tags: php, array

Eu não sei se entendi muito bem na documentação oficial do php (https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php), por isso vim aqui tirar uma dúvida. Eu estou dando uma revisada geral, enfim minha dúvida é:

```
$foo = ["a" => "laranja", "b" => "maça"];
```

Então quando eu acessar o valor de A ou posição 0 será igual a laranja?

PS: Estou meio perdido com isso se entendi ao certo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As declarações de chave do array em PHP são opcionais.

```
$array = ["foo", "bar"];

echo $array[0];
echo $array[1];

//Saídas
"foo"
"bar"
```

Caso as chaves sejam declaradas, o acesso aos seus valores devem ser feitos através da chave especificada.

```
$foo = ["a" => "laranja", "b" => "maça"];

echo $foo["a"];
echo $foo["b"];

//Saídas
"laranja"
"maça"
```

Mas se existir uma mescla de chaves definidas e outras omitidas, o índice será o primeiro valor do array que não possui uma chave declarada explicitamente.

```
$foo = ["a" => "laranja", "b" => "maça", "morango", "c" => "pera", "banana"];

echo $foo["a"];
echo $foo["b"];
echo $foo[0];
echo $foo["c"];
echo $foo[1];

//Saídas
"laranja"
"maça"
"morango"
"pera"
"banana"
```

**UPDATE**

Se você possuir um array dentro de outro array (array multidimensional), o acesso aos seus valores irá depender da associação que foi definida.

```
$foo = [
    "a" => "laranja",
    "pera",
    "vermelhas" => ["um" => "morango", "três" => "maçã", "framboesa"]
];

echo $foo[0];
echo $foo["vermelhas"];
echo $foo["vermelhas"]["dois"];
echo $foo["vermelhas"][0];

//Saídas
"pera"
Array to string
Undefined index: dois
"framboesa"
```

Comment: Ajudou sim! Mas fiquei em dúvida agora que citou, se eu possuo um array igual esse seu $foo, e dentro da chave "a" eu ter um outro array, como ficaria? Não sei se é tão compreensível minha pergunta, mas seria basicamente se cada chave (igual a, b c) tivesse um array dentro como contendo outros valores qual seria o resultado e como faria para acessar? Se possível me explicar na sua perguntar (se der para dar um edit)

Comment: @Devprogramacao, atualizei minha pergunta :)

Answer (score 1):

Nunca havia pensado nisso, mas fazendo testes cheguei à conclusão que **não**. Arrays associativos não permitem que você obtenha o valor de uma posição pelo índice que ela representa, mas dá para descobrir qual a key correta e usar ela para recuperar o valor:

```
<?php

$foo = ["a" => "laranja", "b" => "maça"];

$arrKey= array_keys($foo);
echo $foo[$arrKey[0]];
```

Mas sobre as setas, está correto:
A estrutura é `[chave => valor, chave => valor]`

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_keys.asp
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php

Comment: Uma dica: faz muito mais sentido você citar como fonte a documentação oficial de uma função nativa da linguagem do que uma página mantida por pessoas sem ligação direta com a linguagem.

Comment: Valeu pela dica, adicionei a fonte da documentação oficial.

Answer (score 0):

Essas setas são os operadores que associam índices a valores em `arrays`. Funciona como uma espécie de dicionário, onde `'chave' => 'valor'`. Usando as chaves, irão funcionar como índices, e você não poderá obter eles pela posição de cada um.

```php
$paises = [
    'usa' => 'Estados Unidos',
    'br'  => 'Brasil',
    'lon' => 'Londres'
];

// obtendo por índice
echo $paises[1];     // Erro - não existe uma chave '1'

// obtendo por chave
echo $paises['lon']; // Certo - Londres
```